# In fullcalendar, event title from a google calendar feed isn't showing up

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I've made a Google Calendar to display in fullcalendar. The events display, not the event titles do not. How can I get the event titles to show up, does anyone know?

I made a Google Calendar, went into the developers console and created a new project. Then I enabled the Google Calendar API for that project. Then I created an API key, a OAuth 2.0 client ID, and a Service account key for the project.

Here is my code:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        header: {
            right: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'myapikey',
        events: {
            googleCalendarId: 'post-gazette.com_hsvt6hs1u9b5rhfhursjeq1skg@group.calendar.google.com'
        },
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            alert();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Apologies but I lost the link with the instructions.

If you go to "manage this domain" from in gmail under settings -> apps -> google apps -> calendar -> share settings.

Then under "External sharing options for primary calendars" select option "Share all information and outsiders can change calendars" (other options might work but try this first, as only people using your app with the API key will be able to see you calendar anyway).

Also under "Internal sharing options for primary calendars" I have selected "Share all information" (not sure I changed this though).

Now if you go back to your calendar, then click on the drop down next to "My Calendars" -> "Settings" then edit share settings of your calendar. Make sure all the "Make this calendar public" is ticked and select "See all event details".

I think that does it...obvious really ;-)

Comment: It turns out that, that method doesn't work for my calendar because I was logged in with my organization and my organization prevents our sharing our calendars with the public. I had to log in with my private account, create the calendar there and share it from there.